# boxlayout and page-y axis : does not work, why?

Tags: java, swing, layout

Does anyone know why the content of my window is not put in the center?
The content just goes to the top left corner, whatever modification i make : i can't find out why...
I would like to use a simple BoxLayout on the page-y axis :

```
package myview;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.*;

import Model.Words;

public class MyWindow extends JFrame {
    JLabel myWord = new JLabel();

    public MyWindow(){
        this.setSize(500, 300);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel listPane = new JPanel();
        listPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(listPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        //listPane.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        Words words = new Words();
        this.myWord.setText(words.getWord());
        listPane.add(myWord);
        JLabel myWord2 = new JLabel("test");
        listPane.add(myWord2);
        this.setContentPane(listPane);
        //, BorderLayout.CENTER
        //buttonPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPane, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MyWindow mywindow = new MyWindow();
                mywindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                mywindow.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please use common Java nomenclature (e.g. package names in lower case) 3) Please find your shift ke an apply it to the first word of every sentence, as well as the word 'I' & wherever appropriate for API classes. 4) Don't extend `JFrame`.  5) Don't call `setSize()` 6) `Fenetre`?  What language is that?  Please use English equivalents in code posted to sites based around English.  (Though it is a good principle with any open-source.)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson okay done ;) what about JFrame? and setSize? and would you have any idea about my problem? thanks

Comment: *"okay done"*  Done 'what', exactly?  Noting that I recommended 6 points, but the only one immediately observable as fixed is point (2). *"what about JFrame?"*  Prefer composition over inheritance (search on the phrase).  *"and setSize?"* Call `pack()` instead. *"would you have any idea about my problem?"*  I already mentioned it.  ***Post an SSCCE.***

Comment: @Andrew Thompson : okay just relax... i edited the post to fit the recommendations, would you like that i make the code shorter? i think if i only post the code from the constructor people might not have enough to see where the problem comes. I found out that if i add `listPane` in a another `JPanel()` it works actually, maybe do you have a better option? i'm not sure to use the best technique here... and sorry if it does not suit the requirements, if it's the case please just tell me (and which part of the SSCCE is not followed). And again, relax, uh :)

Comment: *"okay just relax"*  OK just read the freakin' SSCCE document.  If there is anything in it you do not understand, ask.  Most of the questions in your latest comment are explicitly addressed in it.  (And don't worry about me, no stress whatsoever if you fail to get a solution.)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson : okay so just throw up a bit and it will get better. "no stress whatsoever if you fail to get a solution" : i'm here for that, nobody asked you to come and post. I edited my post so that it is short, clear, and with only what's interesting for the readers. So yeah just relax, and if you want to help, just add some more respect, would you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to add `Box.createVerticalGlue`before and after your components in your `BoxLayout`.

Also I'd also use `Box.createVerticalBox` as container.